# React Native: when you navigate away from a component, does that component ever get un-mounted?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, render

In my React Native app, if I have a stack navigator and I navigate from `screenA` to `screenB` with `this.props.navigation.navigate('screenB')`, is it possible that `screenA` would ever get un-mounted?

The reason I ask is that when `screenA` mounts, I make an API call that will load a resource that will be available in all screens via Redux. I might navigate to `screenB` while that API call is still in progress. So I want to know if it's possible that my navigating to `screenB` too soon could prevent the resource from loading and being available in `screenB`.

Comment: It depends on the navigation library you’re using and which controllers (iOS) and fragments (Android) this gets mapped to on the native platform. Generally for pushing onto a stack or switching tabs, ScreenA would not get unmounted, otherwise it would be considered a replacement and would be unmounted.

Comment: @AaronBrager Can you describe any scenarios where it would get unmounted, based on controllers, fragments, or navigation libraries?

Comment: Once your component is mounted it cannot unmount itself you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using `react-navigation` because you mentioned navigating by using `this.props.navigation.navigate('screenB')`.

Assume the screen will never be unmounted. When you load a 'stack', componentDidMount will get triggered when you enter the screen for the first time, but it will not trigger if you go back to that screen, and componentWillUnmount will never trigger.

React Navigation does gives you a few helpers, you can see more in the docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle).